# Android - change background of component while KEEPING selector?

Tags: android, background, selector

Is this possible? I have for example simple linearLayout with selector to create "click effect":

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/clickToChangeColor"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@color/click_effect" />
```

This is selector click_effect:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/pressed" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/unpressed" android:state_enabled="false"/>
</selector>
```

Everything works just fine, but when I press on this layout, I would like to launch activity (like color picker - but it doesn't matter) and then change color of linearlayout for example to blue. BUT: **keep selector "click effect"**. Trying to do this almost for 2 hours, but nothing works...

PS: I know it can be done for example with another layout inside this layout, apply some padding and apply selector to outer layout and then I can change background of inner layout etc - but it's only ugly workaround

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
     <ImageView
                     android:id="@+id/imageViewSelectedColor"
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"

                        android:background="@color/click_effect"
                        android:src="@color/picked color" />
```

Use an image view instead now you can change src according to picked color.

Comment: works but with small workaround - as I can't use setImageResource(my_color) - because my_color is just programatically created color (from color picker activity) I had to use setImageDrawable(new ColorDrawable(my_color)). This of course doesn't work until I added some transparency to "my_color" to see click effect over my_color ;) Anyway thanks

Comment: yes you can add some transparency to the src drawable   and give some padding and margin to the view for better effect.